# Array_Split with grouped string indices

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe that I would like to create sub-arrays within (i.e. chunk) based on groups of string values within the index. I've read how you can pass a list of string values as the indices variable in np.array_split, but my scenario is a bit more complicated and I'm unsure on best approach.

From the below table/array, I'd like to have 2 sub-arrays: one array which includes index string values "Alpha" and "Bravo", the second with values "Charlie" and "Delta"

Example table:

| Index | Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alpha | sample | 12 |
| Alpha | sample | 13 |
| Alpha | sample | 14 |
| Bravo | sample | 15 |
| Charlie | sample | 16 |
| Charlie | sample | 17 |
| Delta | sample | 18 |
| Delta | sample | 19 |
| Delta | sample | 20 |
| Delta | sample | 21 |

Comment: What you show doesn't look like an array but rather a DataFrame, can you provide code to construct it? Also you describe **3** subdataframes but the logic seems to indicate **2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a DataFrame and that you want to split by custom groups:

```
groups = [['Alpha', 'Bravo'], ['Charlie', 'Delta']]

dfs = [g for _, g in df.groupby(df['Index'].map({k: v for v,l in enumerate(groups) for k in l}))]
```

Output:

```
dfs[0]

   Index Column1  Column2
0  Alpha  sample       12
1  Alpha  sample       13
2  Alpha  sample       14
3  Bravo  sample       15


dfs[1]

     Index Column1  Column2
4  Charlie  sample       16
5  Charlie  sample       17
6    Delta  sample       18
7    Delta  sample       19
8    Delta  sample       20
9    Delta  sample       21
```

Or, if "Index" is actually the index:

```
groups = [['Alpha', 'Bravo'], ['Charlie', 'Delta']]

dfs = [df.loc[l] for l in groups]
```

Output:

```
dfs[0]

      Column1  Column2
Alpha  sample       12
Alpha  sample       13
Alpha  sample       14
Bravo  sample       15

dfs[1]

        Column1  Column2
Charlie  sample       16
Charlie  sample       17
Delta    sample       18
Delta    sample       19
Delta    sample       20
Delta    sample       21
```

Finally, if you don't have explicit combinations in mind but just want groups of 2 values (in order), then use:

```
dfs = [g for _,g in df.groupby(pd.factorize(df['Index'])[0]//2)]
```

Comment: Apologize, I edited the post to clarify. It is originally a dataframe, I'm looking to split in 2 subs based on index values and store as two lists of dataframes. I thought array_split was the appropriate approach.